# Python how to read multiple values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a config file named num_list.conf

```
[SMART]
LIST={
    'SMART' : {813,900,907,908,909,910,911,912,918,919,920,921,928,929,930,931,938,939,940,946,947,948,949,971,980,989,998,999}
}
[GLOBE]
LIST={
    'GLOBE' : {817,905,906,915,916,917,926,927,935,936,937*,975,994,996,997},
    'PREPAID' : {922,923,925,932,933,934,942,943,944}
}
[SUN_CELLULAR]
LIST=
    'SUN_CELLULAR' : {922,923,925,932,933,934,942,943,944}
}
```

How to read this dictionary type in python

Comment: Hi, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hi I'm using Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called your file num_list.conf and saved it in D:. You have an asterisk in one of the numbers, so I don't think converting the numbers to floating point or int would be a good idea

This should work:

```
results = {}

with open(r'd:\num_list.conf') as conf:
 for lines in conf:
    if ":" in lines:
        lineval = lines.split()
        name = lineval[0].replace("'","")
        numbers = lineval[-1][1:-1]
        numbers = numbers.split(",")
        results[name]=numbers

print(results)

#result
{'SMART': ['813', '900', '907', '908', '909', '910', '911', '912', '918', '919', '920', '921', '928', '929', '930', '931', '938', '939', '940', '946', '947', '948', '949', '971', '980', '989', '998', '999'], 'SUN_CELLULAR': ['922', '923', '925', '932', '933', '934', '942', '943', '944'], 'PREPAID': ['922', '923', '925', '932', '933', '934', '942', '943', '944'], 'GLOBE': ['817', '905', '906', '915', '916', '917', '926', '927', '935', '936', '937*', '975', '994', '996', '997}']}
```

Comment: Hi @kannu, what if I would like to print only SMART section?

Comment: @LelanCalusay Then instead of  print (results) , just print (results['SMART'])

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way. There exists a module named [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) but it doesn't automatically convert to dictionary. Instead you can keep the dictionary as a json string and load it like so (You will have to change the structure of config file a bit though):

Here is the file:

```
[SMART]
SMART = {"smart":[813,900,907,908,909,910,911,912,918,919,920,921,928,929,930,931,938,939,940,946,947,948,949,971,980,989,998,999]}

[GLOBE]
LIST={"GLOBE" : [817,905,906,915,916,917,926,927,935,936,937,975,994,996,997],"PREPAID" : [922,923,925,932,933,934,942,943,944]}

[SUN_CELLULAR]
LIST={"SUN_CELLULAR" : [922,923,925,932,933,934,942,943,944]}
```

Here is the python code:

```
>>> import configparser
>>> import json
>>> conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> conf.read("config.conf.txt")
['config.conf.txt']
>>> json.loads(conf["SMART"]["SMART"])
{'smart': [813, 900, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 918, 919, 920, 921, 928, 929, 930, 931, 938, 939, 940, 946, 947, 948,
 949, 971, 980, 989, 998, 999]}
```

Comment: If this works, I like this better than my solution.  So much more elegant ! And thanks for introducing me to configparser  !!

Comment: @kannu The key thing is that the list has to be a json string (it is the format). That means, the list has to be inside `[]` instead of `{}`, it has to be in one line(so config parser can parse it properly) and also (though I am not completely sure about this), the dictionary keys have to be in double quotes.

Comment: Hi @khajvah, I tried your code, but i got the result 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call_dict.py", line 6, in <module>
    json.loads(conf["SMART"]["SMART"])
AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute '__getitem__'

This is code:
      import ConfigParser
      import json
     
      conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
      conf.read("config.conf.txt")
      json.loads(conf["SMART"]["SMART"])

Comment: @LelanCalusay I used python3. I dont have electricity right now so i cant test but try `conf.get('SMART', 'SMART')`. Alternatively, read the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) or use python 3. :)